# How get a column's mean based in another column vale

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Random number      Location         Month           Value
xxxxxxx            USA             September         5
xxxxxxx            Canada          September         4
xxxxxxx            Canada          September         4
xxxxxxx            Canada          July              9
xxxxxxx            Italy           February          6
.                   .                  .             .
.                   .                  .             .
.                   .                  .             .
xxxxxxx            USA             January           10
```

How can I get a value's mean in Canada? In my case is 200 Locations , I can't do it one by one. Had another way to get the mean.
Is posible do a dict with the mean?

Tks.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `df.groupby('Location').Value.mean()`

Comment: see the pandas [split-apply-combine docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) -- you'll find what you need there :p

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need:

```
df.loc[df.Location == 'Canada', 'Value'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dictionary containing the mean values for each Country:

```
df.groupby('Location')['Value'].mean().to_dict()

# {'Canada': 5.666666666666667, 'Italy': 6.0, 'USA': 5.0}
```

Comment: That's all I need, tks for the help.